# PlayN getContext() failed in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, playn

Is this a known issue? I was under the impression that IE9 was HTML 5 compatible and supported the canvas tag.

Answer (score 2):

Could you provide a bit more context on the failure? The playn-html initialization code first attempts to create a webgl canvas context (which is **not** supported on IE9), but when this fails, it will fall back to a regular 2d context (which **is** supported on IE9).

I don't have a Windows box handy to check at the moment, but I do know that Angry Birds works on IE9, so unless something has crept into the code in the meantime, it should still work. But any precise information you could provide on the failure you're seeing would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked in the Google group:
[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/playn/browse_thread/thread/a0658addd7814138)

> Looks like it's failing to get a proper  element. You're probably running in IE9's "compatibility mode".
>   Try adding the following to your `<head>`:
>   `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >`
>   (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx)

I have not tried this but aparetly it fixed the problem in the original thread.